'Email' is not defined no-undef while using https://smtpjs.com/ code
I am trying to import a js function in a react file, but it's throwing 'Email' is not defined  no-undef
I am trying to use https://smtpjs.com/ service in my website.
send_mail.js file:
function emailSend(){
    Email.send({
        Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com",
        Username : "username",
        Password : "password",
        To : 'them@website.com',
        From : "you@isp.com",
        Subject : "This is the subject",
        Body : "And this is the body"
    }).then(
      message => alert(message)
    );
}
    
export default emailSend;

homepage.jsx react file:
import emailSend from '../javascripts/send_mail.js'
...
...
<form onSubmit={emailSend}>
...
...
...
</form>

index.html:
...
...
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
</body>
...
...
...

I tried deleting the send_mail.js file and include the code in  tag just after the previous script tag <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script> in index.html itself,
did't work (button works as default like when given no onsubmit attribute, i.e. page just refreshes)
I am very new to JS, any help in what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!
